# Returning the highest 'cuteness' rating in cats object

Tags: javascript, object

How can I fix this problem. Actually this is an exercise about how to use debugger but I couldn't solve the problem.

Fix the `cutestCat` function. Should return the cat with the highest `cuteness`
rating.

*/

```
function cutestCat(cats) {

  let cutest;
  let i = 0;
  debugger
  while (i < cats.length) {
    const cat = cats[i];
    if (cat > cutest) {
      cutest = cat.cuteness;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return cutest;
}

const cats = [
  { name: 'Fluffy', cuteness: 9 },
  { name: 'Princess', cuteness: 6 },
  { name: 'Tiger', cuteness: 7 },
  { name: 'Indie', cuteness: 5 },
]

console.log(cutestCat(cats)); // { name: 'Fluffy', cuteness: 9 }
```

Comment: The comparison should be `if (cat.cutest > cutest)`. If you want the object in return, you'll need another variable, since the code only recorded the max numeric value.  Anyway, a preferable way would be to sort and return the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. you need to compare cat cuteness not cats ie:

```js
if (cat.cuteness > cutest.cuteness){
}
```

2. this comparison requires that the `cutest` variable holds a cat with a `cuteness` property, but starts as `undefined` which will give you an error.
   One possible fix is starting with it as the first cat in the array and initilizing `i` as `0`.

This is the whole snippet:

```js
function cutestCat(cats) {

  let cutest = cats[0];
  let i = 1;
  while (i < cats.length) {
    const cat = cats[i];
    if (cat.cuteness > cutest.cuteness) {
      cutest = cat;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return cutest;
}

const cats = [
  { name: 'Fluffy', cuteness: 9 },
  { name: 'Princess', cuteness: 6 },
  { name: 'Tiger', cuteness: 7 },
  { name: 'Indie', cuteness: 5 },
]

console.log(cutestCat(cats));
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix with either...

```
function cutestCat(cats) {
  let cutest=-MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, cutestCat;
  let i = 0;
  debugger
  while (i < cats.length) {
    const cat = cats[i];
    if (cat.cuteness > cutest) {  // note the new comparison
      cutest = cat.cuteness;
      cutestCat = cat;            // note the recording of the object
    }
    i++;
  }
  return cutestCat;  // note returning the object
}
```

Or, prettier...

```
function cutestCat(cats) {
  let sorted = cats.slice().sort((a, b) => b.cuteness-a.cuteness);
  return sorted.length ? sorted[0] : null;
}
```

Comment: In 1st version, you already have `cutestCat` as full cat object, so why not use `if (cat.cuteness > cutestCat.cuteness)` instead of allocating one more variable ?

Comment: Hi @dhaker. Yes, and and check the length of the array and init `cutestCat` to the first element if there is one? Agree that works, too.  Keeping track of the numeric max does cost another stack variable but saves that check/initialization.  Six of one, half dozen of the other...

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `if` of the `while` loop. You are comparing cat(object) variable with cutest(numeric) variable.

So rather that storing `cuteness` in `cutest` variable, store the object itself. And then you can compare cuteness of both those objects in the `if` condition.

That is:

```js
function cutestCat(cats) {

  let cutest = cats[0];
  let i = 1;
  debugger
  while (i < cats.length) {
    const cat = cats[i];
    if (cat.cuteness > cutest.cuteness) {
      cutest = cat;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return cutest;
}

const cats = [
  { name: 'Fluffy', cuteness: 9 },
  { name: 'Princess', cuteness: 6 },
  { name: 'Tiger', cuteness: 7 },
  { name: 'Indie', cuteness: 5 },
];

console.log(cutestCat(cats)); // { name: 'Fluffy', cuteness: 9 }
```

You might also want to write some conditions to check if the array passed (i.e. `cats`) is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 simple ways to solve this problem.
Reduce

```
function cutestCat(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, rec) => {
    console.log("acc", acc);
    return acc.cuteness < rec.cuteness ? rec : acc;
  });
}
```

For loop

```
function cutestCat(array) {
  if (!array.length) {
    return "some default value";
  }
  let result = array[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    const current = array[i];
    if (current.cuteness > result.cuteness) {
      result = current;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

In your example, you need to make a comparison by the cuteness field, and not compare objects. All objects have different references, so your condition won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.forEach` to loop through them and check for the highest cuteness, like so:

```
function cutestCat(cats) {
  let cutest = cats[0]; // to avoid null reference
  cats.forEach(cat => {
    if (cat.cuteness > cutest.cuteness) {
      cutest = cat;
    }
  });
  return cutest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function cutestCat(cats) {

  let cutest;
  let i = 0;
  while (i < cats.length) {
    const cat = cats[i];
    // if there is no cutest cat to start with, it means this is the
    // first cat, set it as the cutest cat and skip the cuteness
    // comparison
    if(!cutest) {
      cutest = cat;
      continue;
    }
    // if there is already a cat that is considered cutest,
    // compare it with current cat and update cutest if
    // the current cat is more cuter than the one that is already
    // considered cutest
    if (cat.cuteness > cutest.cuteness) {
      cutest = cat;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return cutest;
}

const cats = [
  { name: 'Fluffy', cuteness: 9 },
  { name: 'Princess', cuteness: 6 },
  { name: 'Tiger', cuteness: 7 },
  { name: 'Indie', cuteness: 5 },
]

console.log(cutestCat(cats)); // { name: 'Fluffy', cuteness: 9 }
```